# Angular HttpParams is there a way to add square brackets to serialized query params when generating query params with the same key?

Tags: angular, angular-http

When querying my api with multiple query params of the same key but multiple values it is not interpreting the request properly unless square brackets are added to each key. Let me give you an example:

```
    let params = new HttpParams();

    params = params.append('color', 'blue');
    params = params.append('color', 'red');

    console.log(params.toString()) // color=blue&color=red 
    // Would prefer color[]=blue&color[]=red
```

Is there any way to produce this functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by writing my own interceptor and generating the query string with another library. Please see below:

Install this library:

```
$ npm i query-string --save
```

Add this interceptor:

```
import {
  HttpEvent,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpInterceptor,
  HttpParams,
  HttpRequest,
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import * as querystring from 'query-string';

@Injectable()
export class QueryParamInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor() {}

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    if (!request.params.keys().length || request.method !== 'GET') {
      return next.handle(request);
    }

    let { params } = request;

    let queryParams = this.createQueryParams(params);

    let queryString = querystring.stringify(queryParams, { arrayFormat: 'bracket' });

    let urlWithParams = request.urlWithParams.replace(request.params.toString(), queryString);

    request = request.clone({
      url: urlWithParams,
      params: new HttpParams(),
    });

    return next.handle(request);
  }

  private createQueryParams(params: HttpParams): { [key: string]: string } {
    let queryParams = {};

    for (let key of params.keys()) {
      let values = params.getAll(key);

      if (!values) {
        continue;
      }

      if (values.length === 1) {
        queryParams[key] = values[0];

        continue;
      }

      queryParams[key] = values;
    }

    return queryParams;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can override angulars' HttpParameterCodec not to encode the square brackets:

```
export class MyCustomHttpUrlEncodingCodec extends HttpUrlEncodingCodec {
    encodeKey(k: string): string {
        return super.encodeKey(k)
            .replace(new RegExp("%5B", "g"), "[")
            .replace(new RegExp("%5D", "g"), "]");
    }
}
```

I described my solution a bit more detailed here: http://www.moritz-benzenhoefer.com/angular-http-requests-use-square-brackets-in-httpparams-as-parameter-key-name/

Comment: This also works for **query parameter values** using ```encodeValue``` instead of ```encodeKey```.

Answer (score 2):

I am using Angular 14 and all methods i've tried to get ?param[]=1&param[]=2 in the query string, using HTTPParams() have failed

This hack is the only solution that works for me:

```
const searchRegExp = /%5B%5D/gi;
const replaceWith = '[]';
const queryStringDecoded = params.toString().replace(searchRegExp, replaceWith);
```

And then append the string to the URL

I hope Angular fixes the issue as Symfony PHP framework supports square bracket URL params